# Android app displayed on half of the screen when rotated from landscape to portrait

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

*I have posted this question a while ago, but since then I removed a major part of the code, which may help to find a solution... So I am trying to post again.*

I have created with expo a simple android app that is available here:
https://exp.host/@rahamin/Israel-Weather

Then I created an apk which may be found here:
https://expo.io/artifacts/0328214e-13b1-462a-a803-a3d64ad798f9

(the weird letters are Hebrew…)

- When I start the app within expo in landscape mode and rotate to portrait, everything looks fine.
- However, when I do the same thing with the apk, the app is displayed only on half of the screen.
- In both cases the app looks fine if starting in portrait mode

Screenshots of both cases are attached below.

Any idea how to fix that? The app is using Expo's MapView, doesn't seem to me as relevant to the problem…

Here is the code of the main component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { AppState, Dimensions, View, Text, ActivityIndicator, Image } from 'react-native';
import { MapView } from 'expo';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { CardSection, MyButton } from './common';
import { fetchCountry } from '../actions';
import { PORTRAIT, LANDSCAPE, ACTIVE, INACTIVE } from '../helpers/constants';
import { getCountryInfo } from '../helpers/countryForecastHelpers';
import { israelRegionPortrait, israelRegionLandscape } from '../helpers/mapsHelpers';

class MapDisplay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMapReady: false,
      aboutModalVisible: false,
      helpModalVisible: false,
      region: israelRegionPortrait,
      zoomed: false,
      resetRegion: israelRegionPortrait,
      dim: {},   // { width: , hight: }
      appState: INACTIVE
    };
    this.initRegion = this.initRegion.bind(this);
    this.onRegionChangeComplete = this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this);
    this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
    this.handleDimensionsChange = this.handleDimensionsChange.bind(this);
    this.setDimensionsAndOrientation =
      this.setDimensionsAndOrientation.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const initialDim = Dimensions.get('window');
    this.setDimensionsAndOrientation(initialDim);

    this.addListeners();
    this.props.fetchCountry();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.removeListeners();
  }

  onMapLayout() {
    this.setState({ isMapReady: true });
  }

  render() {

    const countryInfo = getCountryInfo(this.props.country);
    if (!countryInfo) { // loading of data is not done yet
      if (!this.props.country.error)
        return this.renderLoading();
      else
        return this.renderLoadingError();
    } else {

      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <MapView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            zoomEnabled = {true}
            rotateEnabled = {true}
            scrollEnabled = {true}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            mapType = 'satellite'
            region={this.state.region}
            onLayout={this.onMapLayout.bind(this)}
            onPress={(e) => this.onMapPress.bind(this)(e)}
            onRegionChangeComplete={(region) =>
              this.onRegionChangeComplete(region)}
            >
          </MapView>
          {this.renderButtons()}
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  renderButtons() {
    return (
      <CardSection>
        <MyButton text="help" fontSize={14} padding={5}
          backgroundColor="#fff"
          onPress={() => {}}/>
        <MyButton text="refresh" fontSize={14} padding={5}
          backgroundColor="#fff"
          onPress={() => {}} />
        <MyButton text="about" fontSize={14} padding={5}
          backgroundColor="#fff"
          onPress={() => {}}/>
      </CardSection>
    );
  }

  renderLoading() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ActivityIndicator
          size={"large"}
          color={"#00f"}
          style = {{ padding: 10, flex: 3  }}/>
        <Text style={{ flex: 2, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10,
          fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center'  }}>
          Loading...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderLoadingError() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',
            paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10 }}>
          <Text style=
            {{ fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            Error loading data. Please check the internet connection.
          </Text>
          <Text style=
            {{ fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            {' '}
          </Text>
          <Text style=
            {{ fontSize: 28, fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            If everything is OK, please try later.
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View>
          {this.renderButtons()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );

  }

  onMapPress(e) {
    //console.log("In onMapPress. coordinate: ", e.nativeEvent.coordinate);
    this.initRegion();
  }

  initRegion() {
    this.setState({ region: this.state.resetRegion, zoomed: false });
  }

  initData() {
    this.props.fetchCountry();
    this.setState({ region: this.state.resetRegion,
      zoomed: false, isMapReady: true });
  }

  onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
    const delta = (this.state.orientation === PORTRAIT) ?
      region.latitudeDelta : region.longitudeDelta;
    const zoomed = (delta < 2) ? true : false;

    if (zoomed !== this.state.zoomed)
      this.setState({ region: region, zoomed: zoomed });
  }

  addListeners() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', this.handleDimensionsChange);
  }

  removeListeners() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    Dimensions.removeEventListener('change', this.handleDimensionsChange);
  }

  handleAppStateChange(nextAppState) {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === ACTIVE) {
      this.initData();
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
  }

  handleDimensionsChange(windowAndScreen) {
    const { height, width } = windowAndScreen.window;
    this.setDimensionsAndOrientation({ height, width });
  }

  setDimensionsAndOrientation(dimensions) {
    const orientation =  (dimensions.height > dimensions.width) ?
      PORTRAIT : LANDSCAPE;

    const resetRegion = (orientation === PORTRAIT) ?
      israelRegionPortrait : israelRegionLandscape;

    this.setState({ dim: dimensions, orientation: orientation,
      resetRegion: resetRegion, region: resetRegion });
  }

  regionsEqual(region1, region2) {
    return (
      (Math.abs(region1.latitude - region2.latitude) < 0.1) &&
      (Math.abs(region1.longitude - region2.longitude) < 0.1) &&
      (Math.abs(region1.latitudeDelta - region2.latitudeDelta) < 0.1) &&
      (Math.abs(region1.longitudeDelta - region2.longitudeDelta) < 0.1)
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    country: state.country
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,
  { fetchCountry })(MapDisplay);
```

**Starting the app in Portrait mode:**

[image: starting the app in Portrait mode]

**rendering in Portrait after starting the app in Landscape mode**

[image: rendering in Portrait after starting the app in Landscape mode]

Comment: I just need to ask 1 ques, Do you really need the app in landscape mode?

Comment: Just added the code...
Yes. I expect people to use it on tablets, and they may start in landscape an rotate. Even if not too many people do this, I feel embarrassed to upload to google play with such a bug...

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Comment: No. Living with it... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's late but help someone.
This works for me. I added this code in *oncreate()*

```
//mRootLayout is root layout of activity
   mRootLayout.post(new Runnable()
   {
       @Override
       public void run()
       {
           mRootLayout.invalidate();
           mRootLayout.requestLayout();
           mRootLayout.postInvalidate();
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my app i am using the react-native-orientation library, which is working fine. You can try is https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation